# Should I use type or type of in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

> **1. I must condemn your criminal type mentality.**
>
> **2. I must condemn your criminal type of mentality.**

Which one is grammatically correct and preferable?
Can I use kind of in the place of type of?

Answer (score 0):

I would not call sentence (1) wrong, but it is at best awkward. I think that (2) is much smoother and more natural. The expression "*kind of*" can indeed be used in place of "*type of*" with little or no change in meaning.

Comment: In India, there is a special type of valley called **Dun**. Now if I see a valley that looks like *Dun* can I say "This is a Dun type valley" or I should say "This is a Dun type of valley"?

Comment: @Sahil Laskar That would depend on how "Dun" is used in Indian English. Does it function as an adjective, or a noun, or both. I suspect that either form would be acceptable. Interestingly "Dun" is also an element of many place names in Ireland and Scotland, coming from a Gaelic word meaning hill fort. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dun I presume there is no relation.

Comment: Dun is noun. So which one would be appropriate? My another question is 'He is a bad type of person ' or 'He is a bad type person'? Here bad is adjective. So which one should I use ?

Comment: @Sahil I believe " bad type of person " is rather more common, and I would favor it. In the case of "Dun" I still suspect that either would be acceptable, but usage in Indian English would matter, and I don't have experience of that.